# Array of Structures - Functions not pulling through data

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am studying BscCS so I am familiar with programming concepts, however I always seem to get stuck on structs and arrays of structs.

I am required to convert parallel arrays into an array of structs. I have done this, but for some reason the information is not getting sent to the functions properly and the program keeps crashing.

Could you help identify where I am going wrong of if there is something I am missing? I don't need exact code for answers, just some guidance. Here is the code:

```
#define SIZE 3
struct Employee {

string firstName[SIZE];
string lastName[SIZE];
int id[SIZE];
int hoursWorked[SIZE];
int payRate[SIZE];
int stat[SIZE];

};

//Functions
int menu();
void printReport(Employee & employees);
void search(Employee & employees);
void calculatePay(Employee & employees);
void orderByLastName(Employee & employees);
void orderByid(Employee & employees);
void printActive(Employee & employees);
void printInactive(Employee & employees);

//Display Main Menu
int menu()
{
int choice;
cout << "1. Print out Employee Report. " << endl;
cout << "2. Search Employee Records. " << endl;
cout << "3. Display the Report in Sorted order on Last Name or ID. << endl;
cout << "4. Calculate Pay. " << endl;
cout << "5. Display Active Employees." << endl;
cout << "6. Display Inactive Employees." << endl;
cout << "7. Quit" << endl;
cout << "Enter your choice. ";
cin >> choice;

return choice;
}

//Display the employee data in a formatted order
void printReport(Employee & employees)
{
cout << setw(10) << "First Name" <<
    setw(10) << "Last Name" <<
    setw(10) << "ID" <<
    setw(10) << "Hours" <<
    setw(10) << "Rate" <<
    endl;
ios::fixed;
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    cout << setw(10) << employees.firstName[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.lastName[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.id[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.hoursWorked[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.payRate[index] << endl;
}

//Search for employee ID
//Show "Not Found" if unable to locate
void search(Employee & employees)
{
bool found = false;
int idNumber;
int pos = -1;

cout << "Enter id number ";
cin >> idNumber;

for (int index = 0; index < SIZE && !found; index++)
{
    if (employees.id[index] == idNumber)
    {
        found = true;
        pos = index;
    }
}

if (!found)
    cout << "Not Found. " << endl;
else
    cout << setw(10) << employees.firstName[pos] <<
    setw(10) << employees.lastName[pos] <<
    setw(10) << employees.id[pos] <<
    setw(10) << employees.hoursWorked[pos] <<
    setw(10) << employees.payRate[pos] << endl;
} 

//Calculate total weekly pay
void calculatePay(Employee & employees)
{
cout << setw(10) << "First Name" <<
    setw(10) << "Last Name" <<
    setw(10) << "ID" <<
    setw(10) << "Hours" <<
    setw(10) << "Rate" <<
    setw(10) << "Total Pay" <<
    endl;
ios::fixed;
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    cout << setw(10) << employees.firstName[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.lastName[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.id[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.hoursWorked[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.payRate[index] <<
    setw(10) << employees.hoursWorked[index] * employees.payRate[index] <<     endl;
}

//Sort employee data by last name
void orderByLastName(Employee & employees)
{
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++)
    {
        if (employees.lastName[j] > employees.lastName[j + 1])
        {
            string temp = employees.lastName[j];
            employees.lastName[j] = employees.lastName[j + 1];
            employees.lastName[j + 1] = temp;

            temp = employees.firstName[j];
            employees.firstName[j] = employees.firstName[j + 1];
            employees.firstName[j + 1] = temp;

            int tempid = employees.id[j];
            employees.id[j] = employees.id[j + 1];
            employees.id[j + 1] = tempid;

            int temphours = employees.hoursWorked[j];
            employees.hoursWorked[j] = employees.hoursWorked[j + 1];
            employees.hoursWorked[j + 1] = temphours;

            int temppayrate = employees.payRate[j];
            employees.payRate[j] = employees.payRate[j + 1];
            employees.payRate[j + 1] = temppayrate;

        }
    }
 }
}

//Sort employee data by ID
void orderByid(Employee & employees)
{
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++)
    {
        if (employees.id[j] > employees.id[j + 1])
        {
            string temp = employees.lastName[j];
            employees.lastName[j] = employees.lastName[j + 1];
            employees.lastName[j + 1] = temp;

            temp = employees.firstName[j];
            employees.firstName[j] = employees.firstName[j + 1];
            employees.firstName[j + 1] = temp;

            int tempid = employees.id[j];
            employees.id[j] = employees.id[j + 1];
            employees.id[j + 1] = tempid;

            int temphours = employees.hoursWorked[j];
            employees.hoursWorked[j] = employees.hoursWorked[j + 1];
            employees.hoursWorked[j + 1] = temphours;

            int temppayrate = employees.payRate[j];
            employees.payRate[j] = employees.payRate[j + 1];
            employees.payRate[j + 1] = temppayrate;

        }
    }
 }
}

void printActive(Employee & employees) 
{

bool found = false; 
int pos = -1;   

for (int index = 0; index < SIZE && !found; index++)
{
    if (employees.stat[index] == 1)
    {
        found = true;
        pos = index;            
    }

    if (!found) {

        cout << "No active employees." << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << setw(10) << employees.firstName[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.lastName[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.id[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.hoursWorked[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.payRate[pos] << endl;
    }           
 }  
}

void printInactive(Employee & employees) 
{

bool found = false;
int pos = -1;

 for (int index = 0; index < SIZE && !found; index++)
 {
    if (employees.stat[index] == 0)
    {
        found = true;
        pos = index;
    }

    if (!found) {

        cout << "No inactive employees." << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << setw(10) << employees.firstName[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.lastName[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.id[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.hoursWorked[pos] <<
        setw(10) << employees.payRate[pos] << endl;
    }
 }
}

int main()
{

struct Employee employees[SIZE];

//Read first and last name from user
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    cout << "Enter first name : ";
    cin >> employees[index].firstName[index];

    cout << "Enter last name : ";
    cin >> employees[index].lastName[index];

    //Read ID, hours, and pay rate from user
    while (employees[index].id[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter id : ";
        cin >> employees[index].id[index];

        if (employees[index].id[index] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Id number. " << endl;
            cout << "Enter id : ";
            cin >> employees[index].id[index];
        }
    }

    while (employees[index].hoursWorked[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter hours worked : ";
        cin >> employees[index].hoursWorked[index];

        if (employees[index].hoursWorked[index] < 0) 
        {
            cout << "Invalid hours. " << endl;
            cout << "Enter hours worked : ";
            cin >> employees[index].hoursWorked[index];
        }           
    } 

    while (employees[index].payRate[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter Pay Rate : ";
        cin >> employees[index].payRate[index];

        if (employees[index].payRate[index] < 0) 
        {
            cout << "Invalid pay rate. " << endl;
            cout << "Enter Pay Rate : ";
            cin >> employees[index].payRate[index];
        }
    }

    while (employees[index].stat[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter your status. (0 - Inactive, 1 - Active) : ";
        cin >> employees[index].stat[index];

        if (employees[index].stat[index] < 0) 
        {               
            cout << "Enter your status : ";
            cin >> employees[index].stat[index];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
 }

 //Loop to display menu options until user quits program
 while (true)
 {
    //Call menu with options
    int ch = menu();

    //Different options to choose
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:
        printReport(employees[SIZE]);
        break;
    case 2:
        search(employees[SIZE]);
        break;
    case 3:
        int sortType;
        cout << "1.Sort by Last Name." << endl;
        cout << "2.Sort by ID." << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice. ";
        cin >> sortType;

        if (sortType == 1)
            orderByLastName(employees[SIZE]); 
        else if (sortType ==2)
            orderByid(employees[SIZE]);
        break;
    case 4:
        calculatePay(employees[SIZE]);
        break;
    case 5: printActive(employees[SIZE]);
    case 6: printInactive(employees[SIZE]);
        break;
    case 7:
        exit(0);
    }
 }

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would your struct attributes have 'SIZE' amount of everything?

Comment: Present your [MCVE] please

Comment: If you're learning c++, consider using a class containing your struct's elements as attributes and your functions as methods

Comment: First of all you should not have the structure members be arrays. Then for your problem: When you do e.g. `search(employees[SIZE])` then `employees[SIZE]` is ***out of bounds***, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Looking at your code, what you tagged the question with (c++ rather than c); I think the best advice anyone can give is "read about classes & structs, and the concepts of OOP".

Comment: As a side note - string firstName[SIZE]; - how many first names do you plan to have!?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You went from having parallell arrays to having an array of structs of parallell arrays. The struct should hold the data for *one* employee, and you should pass the array around, not a struct. (Don't be afraid to ignore your old code completely and start over. It usually leads to much better results.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program, and I received more than 20 errors before the compiler involuntarily stopped trying to compile any longer. All of them are connected to the lines of code using cout, cin, string, and setw. You need to use these keywords with the std namespace to fix this, and you need to include the `iostream` header file (`#include <iostream>`). Either you can write `std::` in front of all of these keywords (i.e. `std::cout`) or you can declare the namespace in the preprocessor (`using namespace std;`). Also, for `std::setw`, you need to include the `iomanip` header file (`#include <iomanip>`). After that, you're missing a quotation in the menu function and a bracket at the end of the main function. (There's also a couple of problems with initializing the size of the struct members in the declaration, but I'll leave that up to you.) Hope this helped!

Comment: I had that in, sorry - i was just trying to make the code a little smaller for people to read it. My mistake, I shouldn't have taken it out.